# Get Elasticsearch results from Kibana written to a file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Each search done with Elasticsearch in our program gets indexed and can be checked in Kibana.
I would like to get this written to a file instead for each search, so all the information can be passed to a different system. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could just query elasticsearch from the different system. It's better than using files.

If you want to save a query to a file, it's possible by using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET "http://xxxxxxxx:9200/yourindex/_search" -o data.json
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to get this done as a batch job so I know what has been read. The program that reads this data will be stateless and send the data to another system.